# Properties of an audio file using C from the taglib library functions

Tags: c, audio, taglib

I'm trying to find out the properties of an audio file(artist name, title, duration) using C Language which can be accomplished by installing the taglib(specifically **libtagc0-dev**). In one of the examples provided in the [library](http://goo.gl/M7A34f), the following code is given:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tag_c.h>

#ifndef FALSE
#define FALSE 0
#endif

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int i;
  int seconds;
  int minutes;
  TagLib_File *file;
  TagLib_Tag *tag;
  const TagLib_AudioProperties *properties;

  taglib_set_strings_unicode(FALSE);

  for(i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
    printf("******************** \"%s\" ********************\n", argv[i]);

    file = taglib_file_new(argv[i]);

    if(file == NULL)
      break;

    tag = taglib_file_tag(file);
    properties = taglib_file_audioproperties(file);

    if(tag != NULL) {
      printf("-- TAG --\n");
      printf("title   - \"%s\"\n", taglib_tag_title(tag));
      printf("artist  - \"%s\"\n", taglib_tag_artist(tag));
      printf("album   - \"%s\"\n", taglib_tag_album(tag));
      printf("year    - \"%i\"\n", taglib_tag_year(tag));
      printf("comment - \"%s\"\n", taglib_tag_comment(tag));
      printf("track   - \"%i\"\n", taglib_tag_track(tag));
      printf("genre   - \"%s\"\n", taglib_tag_genre(tag));
    }

    if(properties != NULL) {
      seconds = taglib_audioproperties_length(properties) % 60;
      minutes = (taglib_audioproperties_length(properties) - seconds) / 60;

      printf("-- AUDIO --\n");
      printf("bitrate     - %i\n", taglib_audioproperties_bitrate(properties));
      printf("sample rate - %i\n", taglib_audioproperties_samplerate(properties));
      printf("channels    - %i\n", taglib_audioproperties_channels(properties));
      printf("length      - %i:%02i\n", minutes, seconds);
    }

    taglib_tag_free_strings();
    taglib_file_free(file);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

However when I compile the code, I get the following errors:

```
/tmp/ccz8cuR1.o: In function `main':
tag.c:(.text+0x15): undefined reference to `taglib_set_strings_unicode'
tag.c:(.text+0x69): undefined reference to `taglib_file_new'
tag.c:(.text+0x85): undefined reference to `taglib_file_tag'
tag.c:(.text+0x95): undefined reference to `taglib_file_audioproperties'
tag.c:(.text+0xba): undefined reference to `taglib_tag_title'
tag.c:(.text+0xd8): undefined reference to `taglib_tag_artist'
tag.c:(.text+0xf6): undefined reference to `taglib_tag_album'
tag.c:(.text+0x114): undefined reference to `taglib_tag_year'
tag.c:(.text+0x131): undefined reference to `taglib_tag_comment'
tag.c:(.text+0x14f): undefined reference to `taglib_tag_track'
tag.c:(.text+0x16c): undefined reference to `taglib_tag_genre'
tag.c:(.text+0x195): undefined reference to `taglib_audioproperties_length'
tag.c:(.text+0x1d4): undefined reference to `taglib_audioproperties_length'
tag.c:(.text+0x20c): undefined reference to `taglib_audioproperties_bitrate'
tag.c:(.text+0x229): undefined reference to `taglib_audioproperties_samplerate'
tag.c:(.text+0x246): undefined reference to `taglib_audioproperties_channels'
tag.c:(.text+0x273): undefined reference to `taglib_tag_free_strings'
tag.c:(.text+0x27f): undefined reference to `taglib_file_free'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It seems that the library isn't able to find the functions mentioned in the above errors. I'm unable to figure out a way to eliminate these errors and moreover, as I've simply copied and pasted the code from the [reference](http://goo.gl/M7A34f) there shouldn't be any way that the above errors should persist.

Any suggestion would be useful.

Comment: This is a linker problem -- did you forget to link to the library?  Show the commands you use to compile/link...

Comment: @Dmitri I'm compiling the program simply using gcc -Wall tag.c , here 'tag.c' is the name of the program file.

Comment: You need to link with libtag as well.  Try `gcc -Wall -ltag tag.c`

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the mistake, it worked well by executing gcc -Wall tag.c -L/usr/include/taglib -ltag_c

Comment: The question has been answered, in the comments.  suggest @Dmitri or the OP post an answer, the the OP can accept the answer and close the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can first check the location of the header file 'tag_c.h'. In my system, it's path was '/usr/include/taglib' hence I had to modify the include header to:

```
#include <taglib/tag_c.h>
```

Then compile your your code by linking it with tag library using the command:

```
gcc -Wall tag.c -L/usr/include/taglib -ltag_c
```